# css fixed position overlap with banner

Tags: css

I have a div (banner) with fixed position and a div (content) .When I scroll down the div (content), it will overlap with the div (banner) and caused some wording in div (banner) not able to see. I have tried to put z-index on both div but still have same result. Please see my code at Jsfiddle.

`Jsfiddle:`https://jsfiddle.net/ckcheah/731sLxks/

Comment: Always post an [mcve] in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add `background-color` to your banner.

like this:`background-color: #fff;`

actually, you can set your banner `top:0` to fixed it in the top of the frame.